# Most efficient way to have multiple sort MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of theme parks being pulled from a MySQL table. The default query is

```
try
{
$sql = 'SELECT park_id, name, town, state, country
FROM tpf_parks ORDER BY name ASC';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Error fetching parks: ' . $e->getMessage();
//include 'error.html.php';//
exit();
}
```

and sorts by name ASC. I want links above this that will sort the list by state and country (and eventually rating). I also want links that will show only the theme parks, only water parks, only 'other' and 'show all'.

The way I'm looking at it is I need a new php page for each query but that would mean 16 different PHP pages, one for each query. Is there a way to keep it all with one page so the 16 queries all run in one page and clicking a link just loads the newly sorted list replacing the old list?

On top of this I also want an A-Z of links where by clicking one jumps the page down to the letter of the method of sorting e.g. the theme park list is sorted by state, clicking 'K' will jump down the page to the parks in Kansas. I was thinking of these links using html anchors but then how would I echo the results into 26 chucks (one for each letter A-Z).

Sorry for long winded questions but I'm stumped.
Thanks

Comment: i would look at doing this client side. (http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/05/jquery-filter-sort-plugins.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //make a function  

function orderby($select, $var){
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT {$select} FROM tpf_parks ORDER BY {$var}');
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
echo $result;
}
// run a function    
orderby ("park_id, name, town, state, country","name ASC");
//make all the functions you need like this
```

Comment: Thank you, it took me a while to understand the above code due to me being new with PHP and web design in general but it does the job. My next question is how would I go about echoing the results from this query split up into first letters? The Idea is I have A-Z links at the top of page that link to a html anchor in the list for each letter. Currently the code I use to show the results is ` <?php foreach ($parklist as $park): ?> ` Can this be edited to something like ` <?php foreach ($parklist as $park  WHERE FIRST LETTER = A): ?> ` ?

`code`

Comment: I am not sure that I understood your exact need, so I give you thee answers: 1)  ORDER BY {$var} ASC (gives you A-Z sorting to the echo result) also you you can generate links to the echo results inside the function like: echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$result.'">'.$result.'</a>';

Comment: 2) If you want to keep your results separate, run the function in this way: 
orderby ("park_id, name, town, state, country","name LIKE 'A%'");

Comment: 3) If you need to run this, make it like that: if ($result[0]=='A'){ foreach ($parklist as $park) { echo $result; } }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe would be better to use sorting function just for output via some script. (http://tablesorter.com/ etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
   function getQueryOrder($field,$order){
      $query="";
      switch ($field){
         case "park_id":
             $query="SELECT park_id, name, town, state, country FROM tpf_parks ORDER BY park_id ".$order;
             break;
         }
         case "name":
             $query="SELECT park_id, name, town, state, country FROM tpf_parks ORDER BY name ".$order;
             break;
         }
         case [Other-field]:
             ..... 
             break;
         }
      }
      return $query;
   }
```

and then use it:

```
try{
   $sql = getQueryOrder('park_id','ASC');// select the field park_id and order ASC
   $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
```